# Import class from "outside of the project" (Gradle + Scala)

Tags: java, scala, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Gradle project with the following folder structure.

```
project
    ├── build.gradle
    └── src
        ├── main
        └── provided
```

The `main` folder has Scala source files, and the `provided` folder has some Java classes. I would like to import these Java classes in the Scala source code, but unable to do it. I use IntelliJ for editing. Should I write something in the `build.gradle` file, or can it be done in the IDE? When I mark the `provided\java` folder 'Sources root', the classes are still unavailable for import. Also, the build sync removes the mark from the folder.

Comment: You can use Gradle to configure an additional sources directory for your Main sourceSets :  `sourceSets.main.java.srcDir file("src/provided/java")` . IntelliJ should automatically add this directory to the module sources directories.

Comment: you might need to adapt the Gradle code above to use "scala" instead of "java  (not tested with scala)

Comment: Added the `sourceSets` definition above, still can't import classes.

Comment: see sample/simple project here https://github.com/mricciuti/scala-gradle-demo  : I defined the additional sourcesets as above, it's then possible to reference Java classes from Scala code